# How to start with launchd a bash script that calls fswatch with `&`

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, launchd

#### Manually it works

I have a bash script called [git-watch.sh](https://gist.github.com/kbdluv/0ad7effe175e5f52d79078f422eab463#file-git-watch-sh) (gist link) that calls `fswatch` in a loop like this:

```
while read -r line; do
  {
    fswatch -r "$line" | grep --line-buffered -v '.git' | xargs -n1 -I{} git-commit-unattended.sh "$line";
  } &
done
```

(Note the `ampersand`. I had to use it because `fswatch` blocks waiting for change, so the `while` wouldn't get past the first iteration otherwise. It could be interfering with `launchd` though, not sure.)

It works fine if I call it from the command line passing it a file, like

```
git-watch.sh < /Users/kbdluv/Dropbox/dotfiles/git-watch-paths.txt
```

Running `ps aux | grep fswatch` yields:

```
kbdluv           9629   0.0  0.0  4278008    920 s001  S+    5:46PM   0:00.00 grep fswatch
kbdluv           9415   0.0  0.0  4299876   4912 s001  S     5:37PM   0:00.01 fswatch -r /Users/kbdluv/Dropbox/org
kbdluv           9414   0.0  0.0  4315736   4944 s001  S     5:37PM   0:00.01 fswatch -r /Users/kbdluv/Dropbox/dotfiles
```

**Which is what we want.**

---

#### Launchd doesn't

But now I want it to start automatically on login, and I haven't been able to get `launchd` to cooperate.

Here's my `com.user.gitWatchMyPathsOnLogin.plist` [so far](https://gist.github.com/kbdluv/0ad7effe175e5f52d79078f422eab463#file-com-user-gitwatchmypathsonlogin-plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.gitWatchMyPathsOnLogin</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array><string>/Users/kbdluv/Dropbox/dotfiles/scripts/git-watch-my-paths-on-login.sh</string></array>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
   <key>StandardOutPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/com.user.gitWatchMyPathsOnLogin.out</string>
   <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/com.user.gitWatchMyPathsOnLogin.err</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It loads without error. It starts without outputting anything to stderr or stdout either, but here's what `ps aux | grep fswatch` gives me:

```
kbdluv          11550   0.0  0.0  4267768    888 s001  S+    7:56PM   0:00.00 grep fswatch
kbdluv          11545   0.0  0.0  4298088   4932   ??  S     7:56PM   0:00.01 fswatch -r /Users/kbdluv/Dropbox/org
```

It runs `fswatch` only with the *last* line in the `git-watch-paths.txt` file. (The `fswatch` for `dotfiles` is missing.)

And it doesn't auto-commit when a change happens, so I guess the parts `fswatch` is being piped to aren't getting called.

---

What am I doing wrong, or how could I debug this further when `launchd` isn't throwing any error or outputting anything?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you amend `git-watch.sh` to use the "wait" command to wait on the background processes?

```
while read -r line; do
  {
    fswatch -r "$line" | grep --line-buffered -v '.git' | xargs -n1 -I{} git-commit-unattended.sh "$line";
  } &
done

wait
```